# transform first oder logic (FOL) to CNFFormula

Tags: logic, cnf

[image]

This is my problem: I don't know how to transform `∃m : m ∈ N` to a CNF Formula. I just understand the formula `∃x(A(x)vB(X))`.

Comment: Then this is not a programming problem. But something that belongs to https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: It says that For all n, where n is a Natural number such that there exists m that is a Natural number and m is also greater than n. So maybe write a prolog program that proves this. check(N,M)

Comment: So this is a problem in Peano Arithmetic?

Comment: thanks Reema, I think u are right and maybe I should transform the sequence to conjunction formula

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
N(x): x is a natural number
S(x): is a specific object that depends on the object x (Skolem function)
```

```
∀n[N(n) → ⴺm[N(m) ∧ (m>n)]]                # Skolemize existential quantifiers
≡ ∀n[N(n) → (N(S(n)) ∧ (S(n)>n))]          # Drop universal quantifiers
≡ (N(n) → (N(S(n)) ∧ (S(n)>n)))            # Eliminate implication: (α→β) ≡ (¬α∨β)
≡ (¬N(n) ∨ (N(S(n)) ∧ (S(n)>n)))           # Distribute disjunction: α∨(β∧γ)≡(α∨β)∧(α∨γ)
≡ (¬N(n) ∨ N(S(n))) ∧ (¬N(n) ∨ (S(n)>n))   # Conjunctive Normal Form!
```

You can try to write a Prolog DGC grammar to automate this process.